# Unlink image from the server with prepare statment cant find image

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having issue with showing image value, it doesnt find image.

I want to delete image belong to post when I am deleting post, but image values turns emtpy.
need help to find out where I am going wrong in my queries.

My queries :

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

$delete =   $_GET['id']; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT image FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $delete);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($image);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $delete);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();

$filename = '../images/posts/'.$row['image'].'';
  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    unlink($filename);
    echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
  } else {
    echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($row)` give you?

Comment: `NULL 
Warning: unlink(../images/posts/): Permission denied in D:\wamp\www\site\tests\delete.php on line 162
File ../images/posts/ has been deleted` says has been deleted but not deleting actualy, cant find image row is empty `Line 162 is : $filename = '../images/posts/'.$row['image'].'';`

Comment: ok first up, `if (!$row)` throw a 404 error. Secondly, set the permissions for your folder so that php/apache user can write

Comment: Sorry budd didnt get you  if (!$row) what ? this line you mean `$row = $stmt->fetch();` ? and I am at localhost wamp server windows not sure if I can change permisons as they are already set 777

Comment: That looks super dangerous! [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) basically checks for [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) AND [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) and returns TRUE if the targeted file is a directory. You almost deleted all of your images!

Comment: yeah it says that, but dont delete images in folders, images still in folder.

Comment: `$row['image']` value is empty, I dont see where I am wrong in query and why mage value is empty, I check with database and folder there is image in both

Comment: Try $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), this preserves the keys as an associative array, then var_dump($row) to check you got it

Comment: also, do this: `$folder = realpath('../images/posts/')`; and var_dump() it. If it is false, then the relative link is wrong somehow, so run `getcwd()` to discover what folder php is actually in, and re-figure out the relative link

Comment: You have bind result to $image. Try: $filename = '../images/posts/'.$image.'';

Comment: $row = $stmt->fetch(); is misleading as fetch() return true/false/null

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it working had to change `$filename = '../images/posts/'.$row['image'].'';` to `$filename = '../images/posts/'.$image.'';`  like  @Michael Eugene Yuan said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $delete = $_GET['id']; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT image FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $delete);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($image);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

[bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Binds columns in the result set to variables.

[fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Fetch the result from a prepared statement into the variables bound by mysqli_stmt_bind_result().

```
    $filename = '../images/posts/'.$image;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
      unlink($filename);
      echo 'File '.$filename.' has been deleted';
    } else {
      echo 'Could not delete '.$filename.', file does not exist';
    }
}
```

You may use **var_dump($image)** to check the result. If NULL, that means no record is found. You may have to check the value of $_GET['id'] or if record exists in your table.

Comment: Thanks for answer value of the image was empty, I knew its but didnt know how to solve it. Got it working now, had to change `$filename = '../images/posts/'.$row['image'].'';` to  $filename = '../images/posts/'.$image; row wasnt working thanks again.